# Alinhar na mesma linha botões em forms diferentes

Tags: html, css

Bom dia, eu estou com o problema que é, dois botões em forms diferentes não ficam na mesma linha:

```
<div class="w3-row-padding">
    <form action="editar_admin.php" method="POST">
        Nome: <input required type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $rowa['username_Admin']; ?>"style="width: 300px;"><br><br><br>
        Email: <input required type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $rowa['email']; ?>"style="width: 300px;"><br><br><br>
        Senha: <input required type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $rowa['password_Admin']; ?>"style="width: 300px;"><br><br><br>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmar a modificação"></form><br><form action="eliminar_admin.php" method="POST"><input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Eliminar utilizador">
    </form>
</div>
```

Portanto gostaria que alguém me ajudasse a fazer com que o botão **Confirmar** e o botão **Eliminar** fiquem na mesma linha.

Comment: não consegue fazer um exemplo funcional disso? seu código tem classes e css que podem influenciar no layout, se conseguir replicar aqui o problema fica bem mais fácil de ajudar

Comment: mas está usando um outro form só por causa da *action* diferente? poderia usar o mesmo form e apenas mudar a *action* seria mais simples e fácil de fazer o layout que deseja

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tw15c6qj/1/ e em vez de ter os 2 butoes em linhas diferentes, ter na mesma linha

Sim, estou a usar um form diferente para um action diferente, se poder explicar como faço parar ter tudo no mesmo, agradecia

Comment: pode mudar a action no click, veja se essa solução fica boa que posso explicar na resposta: https://jsfiddle.net/p1nrkt60/

Comment: Funcionou, Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei ao certo se é uma boa pratica deixar dois `forms`. Mas o que acontece é que a tag form por default tem `display:block`, por isso os botões ficam separadas um em cada linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No CSS vc pode mudar colocando uma classe na `.Row` que tem os dois `forms` e colocando como `display:inline` por exemplo.

```css
.form-btn form {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />

<div class="w3-row-padding form-btn">
    <form action="editar_admin.php" method="POST">
        Nome: <input required type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $rowa['username_Admin']; ?>"style="width: 300px;">
        Email: <input required type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $rowa['email']; ?>"style="width: 300px;">
        Senha: <input required type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $rowa['password_Admin']; ?>"style="width: 300px;">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmar a modificação">
    </form>
    <form action="eliminar_admin.php" method="POST">
            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Eliminar utilizador">
    </form>
</div>
```

---

**Opção 2** *colocando os botões fora do `form`*

Vc pode usar o atributo `form="nome-ID"` para determinar a qual `form` um `submit` vai se referir. Para isso v coloca um ID na tag `<form id="nome-ID">` e no `<input>` vc coloca `form="nome-ID"`

> O elemento `<form>` ao qual o elemento `<input>` está associado (seu formulário dono). O valor do atributo deve ser um id de um elemento `<form>`. Este atributo permite que você coloque elementos `<input>` em qualquer lugar num documento, não apenas como descendentes de seus elementos `<form>`. Um `<input>` só pode estar associado a um único formulário.

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre essa técnica https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />

<div class="w3-row-padding form-btn">
    <form id="form-n1" action="editar_admin.php" method="POST">
        Nome: <input required type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $rowa['username_Admin']; ?>"style="width: 300px;">
        Email: <input required type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $rowa['email']; ?>"style="width: 300px;">
        Senha: <input required type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $rowa['password_Admin']; ?>"style="width: 300px;">
    </form>
    <form id="form-n2" action="eliminar_admin.php" method="POST">
    </form>
    <input form="form-n1" class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmar a modificação">
    <input form="form-n2" class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Eliminar utilizador">
</div>
```